# C# Имеет ли смысл заменить два взаимосвязанных поля на один Dictionary?

Tags: c#

Предположим, имеется условный класс:

```
public class Class {
    int someField;
    int someFieldPerIteration;
}
```

Поле someFieldPerLevel добавляется к полю someField по окончании каждой итерации/просто добавляется много раз.
Второе поле взаимодействует с первым и только с ним.

Собственно, в голову мне пришла идея вместо этих двух полей создать поле-словарь, где ключ будет аналогом первого поля, а значение — аналогом второго. Мне показалось, что это будет удобнее в плане работы, но подводных камней этой затеи я не знаю:

- Есть ли какой-то смысл с точки зрения логики?
- Действительно этот вариант будет удобнее?
- Есть ли просадки по производительности?
- Не является ли такой вариант просто-напросто убогим недокодом?

Comment: Эм, сейчас вы работаете с одним объектом, а хотите использовать коллекцию. У вас этих объектов много?

Comment: Dictionary - очень тяжёлая структура данных. Использовать её для пары значений - сильный оверхед. Полагаю, вам подойдёт [KeyValuePair](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.keyvaluepair-2?view=netcore-3.1)

Comment: используйте не поля, а свойства и реализуйте эти свойства уже как хотите.

Comment: @tym32167 Не припоминаю, что писал, что не буду использовать свойства. Ваш ответ довольно-таки раздраженный

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Всего объектов планируется около сотни. Как уже подсказали выше, с таким количеством объектов использование словаря будет не лучшей затеей

Comment: мой комментарий не раздраженный, он совершенно обычный. Я пишу много комментариев, потому не трачу время на реверансы, но и целей как то вас ущемить у меня тоже нет. Ваш вопрос непонятен, потому тут чего то большего сложно советовать. Попробуйте добавить больше деталей, как конкретно вы используете ваши поля - деталей не текстом, в кодом.

Comment: Производительность легко измерить, берите `Stopwatch` или каноничный `Benchmark.NET` и измеряйте, второй вам еще и расход памяти померяет. Еще словарь имеет ограничение - ключ должен быть уникальным. В остальном - делайте, как вам удобнее. :) Смайлик, чтобы показать, что комментарий не раздражительный (не сарказм). :) По пунктам: 1. Да, 2. Вам решать, 3. Измеряйте, 4. Нет.